# Generating multiple similar reports based on one query - MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to generate a number of related histograms from one query in MS Access 2010. What I have is two columns, A target size, and a real life measurement. I need to split up each histogram by target size, so that it is very clear which measurements are outliers, and which are actually part of another target size grouping.

I have a table where you can specify which target sizes you're interested in seeing, then a query which joins that with other tables to come up with a list of target sizes, and real life measurements.

Ex.

```
+-----------+--------+     +-----------+
| tgtHeight | Height |     | tgtHeight |
+-----------+--------+     +-----------+
| 900       | 984    |     | 900       |
| 900       | 910    |     | 1600      |
| 1600      | 1744   |     +-----------+
| etc...    |        |
+-----------+--------+
```

Is it possible to tell a report to only select the values from the first table where tgtHeight = 900, either in VBA or SQL (In a manner where I don't have to create a new report for each tgtHeight histogram)?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenReport method includes a where argument.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview,,"tgtHeight =900"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238032(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thank you Remou, I ended up using the open args parameter, I couldn't seem to get the WHERE argument to work. My issue now is getting the same report to open multiple times, since it doesn't work by default.

Comment: You are much better off with the Where argument, multiple reports will be much easier. What problem(s) did you have? What OpenArgs did you use and how did you process them?

Comment: The problem I had was that regardless of what I sent as the WHERE clause, the data processed and plotted was the same. This is the "Row Source" SQL for the chart object:

SELECT tblBins.bin_name AS bin_name, Sum(Log.height IS NOT NULL)  * -1 AS [Count]
FROM tblBins
LEFT JOIN qryHeightByTgtHeight
ON (qryHeightByTgtHeight.height < tblBins.bin_max) AND (qryHeightByTgtHeight.height >= tblBins.bin_min)
GROUP BY bin_name;

Comment: The OpenArgs I used was just the desired tgtHeight as an Integer. I then used that to populate my binSize table, although now that I think about it, that isn't sufficient and I need the WHERE argument to work...

Comment: I guess it may not work with charts, I have not tested. In the past, I have modified charts by modifying the sql of the query on which the chart was based and then running the chart. This may be an easier option for multiple charts. It will certainly allow you to use a proper where statement.